# change the color in sprintf

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the code like this

```
    $output.='<li class="'.$rcclass.'">' . 
/* translators: comments widget: 1: comment author, 2: post link */ 
sprintf(_x('%1$s on %2$s', 'widgets'), get_comment_author_link(), '<a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID) ) . '">' . get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID) . '</a>') .
 '</li>';
```

I want %1$s to have a different color than %2$s.
How'd I do that here.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap them in `<span>`s with a specific class, e.g.

```
<span class='comment-author'>%1$s</span> on <span class='post-link'>%2$s</span>
```

and then adapt your CSS to show different colors for those classes.

Comment: odd tried this sprintf(_x('%2$s (<span style="font-family:arial;color:green;font-size:10px;">%1$s</span>)', 'widgets')  the color doesnt change but fonts do!!

Comment: Then whatever gets inserted in the placeholders probably has a color set overriding your choice. Try using `!important` in your own style.